# Excel: Display a Dimension as datatable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas

i want to get data from a cube dimension as a table view. E. g. i have a Dim_Customer Cube (SSAS) table. Now i want to view the contents of only this dimension e. g. CustomerNumber, CustomerName, Street, Postalcode and Country.

Do you know a way to "change" the way of displaying data in a pivot table or use a piveot table as a normal table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function by right clicking the pivot table and set checkbox button
"classic pivot table layout". Select PivotTable Options. In the PivotTable Options dialog, click Display tab and check Classic PivotTable Layout to enables dragging fields.